# Fill in space between multiple objects

Tags: objects, edit-mode, image

I created a model basically composed of a number of spherical shapes in 3D. I would know like to fill the space between the these objects. More or less like cement around bricks.

I have looked around wuite a bit and could either not find a solution or not understand it.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [boolean operations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) you can add the cement as one object. Then subtract it by setting a boolean modifier to difference and adding the objects in between as the subtractor.

[image]